# Estimate for an Integral

Tags: definite-integrals, improper-integrals

In Evan's PDE book, as part of the proof that convolution with the fundamental solution solves Poisson's equation, he makes the following argument:
$$
C_1 \int_{B(0,\varepsilon)}|\Phi(y)|dy\leq C\varepsilon^2|\log\varepsilon|,
$$

where $C_1$ is some constant and 
$$
\Phi(x) = -\frac{1}{2\pi}\log|x|,\qquad x\in \mathbb{R}^2.
$$

My issue is that I don't understand at all how he's bounding the integral. I don't even know where to begin. Can someone help me sort this out? He also handles the case $n\geq 3$ (the function isn't a logarithm), which I also don't understand. But I figure I'll be able to figure that out if I can get some help for this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Use polar coordinates and

$$\int_0^\epsilon r\log r  \, dr = \frac{1}{2}\epsilon^2 \log \epsilon - \frac{1}{4} \epsilon^2$$

Comment: I did some work using this hint and got that, if $\varepsilon < 1$ then the integral of the absolute value evaluates to $\frac{1}{2}\varepsilon^2|\log\varepsilon |+\frac{1}{4}\varepsilon^2$, and if I assume further that $\varepsilon < \mathrm{e}^{-1/2}$, then $\frac{1}{2}<|\log\varepsilon |$, so I can bound the whole thing by $\varepsilon^2|\log\varepsilon|$. Since Evans is ultimately taking $\varepsilon\to 0$ in the overall proof, I figure the restrictions I used on $\varepsilon$ are reasonable. Does this seem about right?

Comment: @428:  That's good.  $\frac{1}{2}\varepsilon^2|\log\varepsilon |+\frac{1}{4}\varepsilon^2 = \varepsilon^2|\log\varepsilon| \left(\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2 |\log \varepsilon|}\right)$ and that second term goes to $0$ pretty fast.  I looked at that book once. It takes a few hours to read one page because so many steps are missing.